# iPad Air screen is black and unresponsive

Tags: ipad

The screen of my 2014 iPad Air, is black and unresponsive, currently the alarm is going off (so I know it is working) but the screen is black and unresponsive. I have not dropped it, I have tried to power it off, but since there is no response, I don't know whether it had any effect.

I have charged it fully overnight. I tested the charger on another device and it works fine. I don't have another Mac computer to connect it to. Yesterday was the first time I used Siri, could that have something to do with it?

What else could I try?

Comment: So if you connect the iPad to your Mac with a USB cable, does it appear in iTunes?

Comment: It appears that Jogar has no Mac to connect the iPad Air to. Did you try resetting it by holding both buttons down for ~ 10 seconds? (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430) That should force the iPad to reboot.

Comment: are you ready to loose all settings and do the factory reset ?

Comment: Just to be clear - holding both buttons down is -not- a factory reset, and will not cause a loss of settings (Buscar - I realize you didn't say this, but I wanted it to be clear.)

Comment: Holding both buttons down is like a soft reset.... Is there any response from connecting a charger? Can you connect it to any computer at all with iTunes? That will help us with giving you the next steps :)

Comment: Is VoiceOver turned on? Triple-click the home button.

Answer (score 1):

I like to connect devices with no visible display to iTunes and see that I can make a backup of the device. At that point, I follow the 6 step process (even if I don't think the first few will work, sometimes going through the shutdown motions revives the screen.)

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3281

If you can make a backup, you have a good base and then can try a restore. Also, if you haven't powered it off, that might do the trick without needing a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The black screen behavior could be caused by VoiceOver being turned on.  It's easy to accidentally do this, and, unless you know what's happened, difficult to turn it back off.

Try triple-tapping the screen with three fingers.  If VoiceOver and the Screen Curtain are on, this will turn off the screen curtain. You can then turn off VoiceOver by connecting to iTunes or by following the instructions at http://www.personalmacgeniuses.com/2011/05/19/trapped-in-voiceover-limbo/.

It's also possible that VoiceOver is configured to activate if the home button is triple clicked.  It's easy to do this when playing with Siri.

Comment: Yes - that could be easily tested by turning up the volume or using earphones.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to solve by pushing both the **power** and the **home** buttons at the same time in order to force it to restart.

I've had this problem with two iPad Air 2, now I'm trying a third one. In my case it always happens after I charge it when the battery reaches the 83% of its capacity.

I recommend you to go to an Apple Store. A nearly 600 € device, I have the 64 Gb model, shouldn't have this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

When the "official" solution didn't work (holding down power and home buttons at the same time), I found a YouTube posting by a very young fellow who had the perfect answer. Despite the fact that he wiggled during the entire video, he showed how to hold down the home button at the same time you plug in the power cord; immediately unplug the cord, and the device will restart. I was never so happy to see that white apple in the middle of my screen.

Answer (score -1):

You might have broke it by over heating or dropping it, take it to the apple store.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Asker states he did not drop it. "Take it to the apple store" could be an answer to almost any question here, I think he's looking for things to try before that step...